# Tablas y overflow-y

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, tablas, flexbox

```
<div class="container">
   <table class="table table-dark table-responsive-xl" style="max-height: 200px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Cargo</th>
      <th scope="col"><a style="color:white" href="/creacion"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></i></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      {{#each data}}
      {{#if estado}}
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">{{id}}</td>
      <td>{{nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
      <td>{{role}}</td>
      <td>
        <a style="color:white" class="p-2" href="/edit/{{id}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a class="trash" style="color:white" href="" myid="{{id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{else}}
     <tr class="bg-danger titulos">
      <th scope="row">{{id}}</th>
      <td>{{nombre}}</td>
      <td>{{email}}</td>
      <td>{{role}}</td>
      <td>
        <a style="color:white" class="p-2"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a><a class="check" style="color:white" href="" myid="{{id}}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/if}}

    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
        </table>    
</div>

CSS:

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vh;
    max-width: 580px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola buenas, tengo un problema con la tabla que estoy haciendo, cuando la uso en celular se comporta bien y crea 2 scroll x-y correspondientes dentro de la tabla permitiendo acceder a toda la tabla sin deformar otros elementos de la web. pero cuando la uso en una laptop se ve asi y cada vez que se crea un usuario nuevo sigue avanzando hacia abajo. Alguna idea? Puedo dejar el codigo pero no es mas que un par de clases de bootstrap y un contenedor con display:flex, justify-content:center;

Comment: Buen día, para poderte ayudar si es necesario que pongas tu código, estilos que le aplicas a la tabla,  por que para determinar desde la imagen es complicado.

Comment: Hola ya edite la publicacion con el codigo. si necesitas mas informacion me avisas. Mi objetivo practicamente es que mi tabla sea dinamica que ya lo es. y que en vez de expandirse hacia abajo sea un cuadro de un tamaño que ya coloque y permita moverse con un scroll hacia arriba y abajo

Answer (score 0):

Bien estuve validando tu codigo, y funciona correcto en dispositivos moviles por que el bootstrap le asigna una propiedad  `display: block` a la tabla.
Si le agregas una misma propiedad a tu tabla funcionara.

```
.table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vh;
    max-width: 580px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yo agregue un display inline, pero puede ir block, o flex, pero en flex necesitas especificar el wrap y flow

Comment: Les recomiendo usar las clases de Bootstrap, para evitar crear contenido CSS que ya existe en la librería: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/